# jQuery UI sortable on select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to get jQuery UI default sortable to work on options in a select multi list box but can't seem to get it working. Can this work with a select option? I've only seen examples with `<li>` everywhere.

Here's my JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#secondSelectms2side__dx" ).sortable();
    $( "#secondSelectms2side__dx" ).disableSelection();
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<select title="" name="secondSelectms2side__dx" id="secondSelectms2side__dx" size="8" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="4">asdsdsds</option>
    <option value="10">bsdsdsdsd</option>
    <option value="2">csdsdsds</option>
</select>​
```

My code is on jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/noscirre/DRUPe/

Comment: I've never tried it, but I'm pretty sure you can't to this on a select element. You could however, use jQuery to break the options out into an ul / li arrangement, then multiselect + sortable them there.

Comment: @user1038814 I can give you a working demo with multiselect which is sortable in `select` box you keen I have demo ready for you?

Comment: @Tats_innit Yes please, that would be brilliant. Thanks

Comment: @user1038814 cool gimme 2 mins, see ya soon!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Workind demo** for select options sorting using multiselect js widget: http://jsfiddle.net/QRv6d/9/

good link: https://github.com/yanickrochon/jquery.uix.multiselect  <strike>http://quasipartikel.at/2009/05/10/jqueryui-multiselect/ **&** http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/</strike>

please note: I cannot find any simple sortable implementation of sortable() with `select boxes` hence using this multiselect plugin and as you can see in demo it does work `:)` you can use it according to your need. full HTML is in js fiddle.

Hope this helps,

**script** source

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/js/ui.multiselect.js"></script>
```

**code**

```
  $(function(){

            $(".multiselect").multiselect();

        });​
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="countries" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">

    <option value="AUT" selected="selected">Austria</option>
    <option value="DEU" selected="selected">Germany</option>

    <option value="NLD" selected="selected">Netherlands</option>

    <option value="USA" selected="selected">United States</option>


  </select>
```

**Image**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll try and adapt that. Cheers

Comment: Dead links @Tats_innit

Comment: Shot bro @Howie . I have updated the link bruv, Will look into the demo, but you can actually see the git repo to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need.  You'll have to do some extra work if you want to customize the stlying to 'look' like a traditional select box.  I'm integrating this with simple_form and will post the code here.

https://github.com/thgreasi/ui-sortable-multiselection